# ubuntu 20.04 NFS Share - permissions lost for nobody:nogroup on reboot

Tags: server, 20.04, permissions, mount, nfs

I am new to Ubuntu/linux, so, most of the config comes from reading guides.

Please bear with me.

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 server with the intention of using a NFS share as a NAS for a Hikvision camera.

This worked perfectly for a few months until I rebooted the server, and, the camera could not "see" the share. Rebooting the camera had no effect.

The error was (from memory) that the share path was not accessible.  re-running

```
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /media/jack/camera1
```

Fixes it until reboot.

I am unsure how to fix this, can anyone advise?  Why do the permissions get lost on reboot?

Steps I took to configure the server /share:

1. Create a ext4 disc partition with the mount point  `/media/jack/camera1`
2. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
3. `sudo apt -y install nfs-kernel-server`
4. add the following to etc/exports

   `/media/jack/camera1     *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)`
5. `cd/media/jack/camera1`
6. `sudo rmdir lost+found`
7. `sudo chown nobody:nogroup /media/jack/camera1`
8. `sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server`

At this stage, I can connect to the share from the camera and store footage.
When the server reboots, the camera cannot "see" the drive, until I run

```
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /media/jack/camera1
```

Then I am back in business.

Appreciate any help you can give

Comment: Your mount point problems are going to be related entirely to how `/media/jack/camera1` is mounted by the way, you may need to use manual mount options in the future to make it work the way you intend.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Can you provide a few more details that I can research about how to do this, so I can read up more?  Maybe even an example for a beginner?

Comment: Linux always mounts as root by default.  This is annoying but classical.  If you are very lazy, run as root.